# React Typescript Discriminate type if prop is missing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, discriminated-union

I am trying to create a select with a clearable prop which allows a clearable button to be clicked, which when clicked calls the `onChange` handler with `null` as the value. When `clearable` is set as true I want `onChange` handler to be typed as `T | null => void` and when it is set to false I want it to be typed as just `T => void`. That part is not a problem, the problem arises when I want the default value for `clearable` to be `true` which allows the user to call the select component without specifying the `clearable` prop and have the `onChange` typed as if `clearable` was true. Please see code below and let me know how to type the `SelectProps` to set the `onChange` properly when `clearable` is not set.

```
type SelectProps<T> = {
  options: T[];
  value: T;
} & (
  | {
      clearable: false;
      onChange: (val: T) => void;
    }
  | {
      clearable?: true;
      onChange: (val: T | null) => void;
    }
);

const Select = <T extends string>({
  options = [],
  value,
  clearable = true,
  onChange,
}: SelectProps<T>): React.ReactElement<SelectProps<T>> => <div>select</div>;

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {/*Works, onChange val is typed to string */}
        <Select
          clearable={false}
          options={[]}
          value=""
          onChange={(val) => console.log(val)}
        />

        {/*Works, onChange val is typed to string OR null */}
        <Select
          clearable={true}
          options={[]}
          value=""
          onChange={(val) => console.log(val)}
        />

        {/* Doesn't Work, onChange val is typed to any */}
        <Select options={[]} value="" onChange={(val) => console.log(val)} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Note, none of the following work:

```
{
  clearable: false;
  onChange: (val: T) => void;
} | {
  clearable: true | undefined;
  onChange: (val: T | null) => void;
}

// Or using a separated "undefined" case...
{
  clearable: false;
  onChange: (val: T) => void;
} | {
  clearable: true;
  onChange: (val: T | null) => void;
} | {
  clearable: undefined;
  onChange: (val: T | null) => void;
}


// Or defining a case without the "clearable" prop
{
  clearable: false;
  onChange: (val: T) => void;
} | {
  clearable: true;
  onChange: (val: T | null) => void;
} | {
  onChange: (val: T | null) => void;
}
```

Comment: [This might just be a React thing because this playground should mimic how JSX is handled and yet it cannot reproduce the error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgZwMYCc4Fs4DsCGwIAmUAvFAN4CwAUFLVAYqhtngPYoBcUAZjgDYIIAbmp0owHCgDmEYFwAUcqAmBosUgJQkAfMtXYpIqgF8oAH3Ki6DZGky5g7APxdVAV2FXaE6bIVKVNSlzKCw3Pj4tYl1AgyNjI2oCCCQ+SWhuNywkYDhWLB4sAB4YKAgAD3wsAgRYRjsWfAJteQIuGA12gG0AIh8ZYB6AXUSqbix5Mnp65gd2Ll4BCAAacUkBhQA3KN0enqhjDSNxyenbWbZOcRQPVf6-KHltnSg9g6PqE6n7pXkd1-2hyEQA)

Comment: Yeah I guess no one has an answer or workaround for this. Hmm seems to be an issue.

Comment: Have you tried using the `never` type? It helped me in my case but it was slightly different than yours (mine was `false` by default instead of `true`).